# Add a number only when a radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to add a number to total amount based on radio button select only if user selects radio button with `value = "serfeeadd"` so I need to check it, get it and add it to the total but I can't figure out why its not working but when I remove `scope = this` and only use `$scope` directly it kinda works, I just need the value assigned to the variable.

I am trying to build a magento wristband designer app everything is built only stuck with this part .

The code has been modified to provide you guys with an overview for anything more you can let me know.

```js
var app = angular.module('wdWristbandDesigner', []);
  app.controller("fontCtrl", MainController);

function MainController($scope){

  //scope
  var scope = this;
  
  scope.foo = function(){
    if (scope.serialisationFeeCheck == 'serfeeadd') {
    scope.serialisationFee = 10;
    console.log(scope.serialisationFeeCheck);
  }
  else {
    scope.serialisationFee = 0;
  };
  }

};
```

```html
<section class="wd-section" ng-controller="fontCtrl as fs">
  <input type="radio" name="serialno" data-ng-model="serialisationFeeCheck" value="no"  >No
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="serialno" data-ng-model="serialisationFeeCheck" value="our">Yes(Our Choice)
            <br>
            <input type="radio"  id="chk" name="serialno" data-ng-model="serialisationFeeCheck" value="serfeeadd" >Yes(Your Choice)
<button typ="button" ng-click="foo()" >click</button>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-click should be fs.foo() and all of your ng-models need the fs object applied to them.

Comment: sorry rob that mistake i only made over here i have those corrected in my codes i am not even calling this function in my codes i just need serialisation fee value correctly according to radio button selection which i am not getting